# Get the name of a null field in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a huge class with members, and i want to check on each member if its null. I don't want to add it manually, just run a for loop (or something similar) which will go over all the fields without 'human' addition every time a field is added.

So far, i can go over the fields, and receive the name of the fields (which is what i need). However, there's nothing on [Field](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) that checks if the value of it is null.

Here's what i have so far :

```
private class Test {
    String name1 = null;
    String name2 = "test";
    String name3 = null;
}

Test mainTest = new Test();
   for (Field field : mainTest.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.isValueNull())
            Log.i("test", field.getName() + " is missing ");
   }
```

`field.isValueNull()` -> this is the method i'm looking for.

In this example, the print will be :

`name1 is missing`

`name3 is missing`

Comment: you can check this similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362212/what-is-the-best-way-to-know-if-all-the-variables-in-a-class-are-null

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get()` method of the `Field` object:

```
   Test mainTest = new Test();
   for (Field field : mainTest.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.get(mainTest) == null)
            Log.i("test", field.getName() + " is missing ");
   }
```