# Check if attribute from object is not null with Option Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have a object from the following class,

```
public class Customer { 
    private String email;
    private String name;
}
```

How can I check whether every attribute is not null using Optional from java 8? Or there is another less verbose way?

Comment: Why do you think `Optional` should be used here? Do you want answers to be **restricted** to the use of `Optional` or do you accept different answers too?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what `Optional` does. It's a type like any other, so you need to *use* it as the type of your variables to garner its benefits.

Comment: I always recommend watching [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14) (by one of the designers) to people that misunderstood `Optional`. It explains when to use it and when to not use it. Maybe it helps you too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to know if all the variables in a Class are null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362212/what-is-the-best-way-to-know-if-all-the-variables-in-a-class-are-null)

Comment: if for some reason you're insisting on a java-8 solution then there is also an answer here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362212/what-is-the-best-way-to-know-if-all-the-variables-in-a-class-are-null/40238927#40238927

Comment: It is not a Optional restrict. If there's any other way less verbose it can do.

Comment: Don't understand people that put negatives value in a simple question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With out reflection you can't check all in one shot (*as others mentioned, Optional not meant for that purpose*). But if you are okay to pass all attributes

```
boolean match =  Stream.of(email, name).allMatch(Objects::isNull);
```

You can have it as an util method inside your Class and use it.

Comment: Just as a note, this answer does not answer the question **if** OP only wants solutions using `Optional`. OP will need to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check whether every attribute is not null using Optional
>   from java 8?

[Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) is NOT meant for checking nulls. Rather it is intended to act as a container on your objects / fields and provide a null safe reference. The idea is to relieve programmer from checking null references for every field in a sequence of operations covering multiple fields. What you are asking for is exactly opposite of what Optional is supposed to help with.

[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) is a good article explaining the purpose of `Optional`.